# Visual Studio, Deployment project and file copy

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I am using Visual Studio 2008 on a C# project.
My programs requires around 300 data files (txt, dbf and csv mostly). I use a post build command line to copy those files into the output directory (so far so good).

```
MKDIR $(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)system
XCOPY $(ProjectDir)system $(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)system /S /Y
```

I also have a deployment project to facilitate the program installation on my users' computers. My problem is that I cannot find a way to make the installer copy the "system" directory from my project output directory into the installation directory.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
As I still cannot find a solution ot this issue, I am trying the followings:

1. to script (postbuild event) the directory copy from the program project to the deployment output like this (working):

   MKDIR "$(ProjectDir)$(Configuration)\system"
   XCOPY "$(ProjectDir)..\Track\bin\x64\$(Configuration)\system" "$(ProjectDir)$(Configuration)\system" /S /Y
2. to script the directory copy from the deployment programm execution folder to the installation directory. Something like this:

   MKDIR "$(InstallationDir))\system"
   XCOPY "$(DeploymentAppDirectory)\system" "$(IstallationDir)\system" /S /Y

But I cannot figure how to make the second point

Comment: Do you see anything in the Build Output?

Comment: I see no error nor embedding/packaging of the concerned files and directories

Answer (score 0):

try to add quotes like so:

```
MKDIR "$(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)system"
XCOPY "$(ProjectDir)system" "$(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)system" /S /Y
```

Comment: The "system" repository is not missing in the output directory of my program project. But it is missing in the deployment project output directory and it the installation directory. Still I gave a try to your solution  but it did not change anything.